# Ошибка ImportError: cannot import name при импортировании переменной

Tags: python

Возникла проблема при импортировании переменной из одного файла Python в другой.

Есть два файла `FirstFileTest.py` и `SecondFileTest.py`

Из файла `FirstFileTest.py` в `SecondFileTest.py` мне нужно импортировать переменную `UserInput`

Код `FirstFileTest.py`:

```
import settings

import discord

from discord.ext import commands

logger = settings.logging.getLogger("bot")

def run():
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True

    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="st!", intents=intents)

    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        logger.info(f"User: {bot.user} (ID: {bot.user.id})")

    @bot.command()
    async def TestUser(ctx, UserInput):
        await ctx.send(UserInput)
        os.system('python SecondFileTest.py')

    bot.run(settings.DISCORD_API_SECRET_KEY, root_logger = True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Код `SecondFileTest.py`:

```
from FirstFileTest import UserInput

print(UserInput)
```

При выполнении выдает ошибку:

```
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\DiscordBot\SecondFileTest.py", line 2, in <module>
from FirstFileTest import UserInput
ImportError: cannot import name 'UserInput' from 'FirstFileTest' (C:\Users\User\Desktop\DiscordBot\FirstFileTest.py)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно исправить

Comment: В FirstFileTest.py нет переменной   UserInput. И непонятно чего ты таким импортом хочешь достичь.

Comment: У тебя не получится таким образом импортировать значение, которое передается функции. Можешь, например, создать в файле SecondFileTest.py функцию, а потом, предварительно импортировав функцию из второго файла в первый (``from SecondFileTest import func``), можешь вызвать ее, передав нужный параметр.